# I have two groups of data with (the same) two variables each, how can I plot these groups against eachother?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, data-visualization, boxplot

Please bare with me, I am very new to statistics.

I have two data groups (Location A and Location B), at both locations I recorded two variables (Noise and Activity), I am trying to find out how I can compare the two in one plot, is this possible?

Essentially, I would like to plot Noise/Activity at Location A against Noise/Activity at Location B. I currently have this [image: Boxplot showing Activity ~ Location]

However, I would ideally like to have a plot that plots both, I am not bothered if it is not a boxplot, just whatever would be best.

The only other issue is that my Noise values are pretty high, and so any plots are really skewed, for example

[image: Plot Activity ~ Noise]

Could anyone advise where to go from here?

Many Thanks

Comment: I suggest that you do a scatter plot of activity vs noise with different markers (symbols or colours) for the two locations. This way you can see at the same time the relations between the two variables and their relation with the location.

Comment: @Ertxiem You could turn that into an answer.

Comment: I think this question would benefit from some example data and the code used to produce the plots. this would make advice much easier.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you do a scatter plot of activity vs noise with different markers (symbols or colours) for the two locations. This way you can see at the same time the relations between the two variables and their relation with the location.
Something like this figure with made up data:

[image: activity vs noise in road or park]